# Geolocate using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, geolocation, ip

One of my friends recently gave me their old web designer magazines, and there's a small tutorial on how to show the visitor's location using Google or Bing Maps API.

Here's the code they gave: [The Code](http://n1x.co.uk/geolocation.txt).

The thing is, the guys who wrote the tut said that the given code should be passed on to Google/Bing Map APIs, but I don't know how to do that.

Please Help!!

**P.S. I am *very* bad at computer languages, so please describe as clearly as possible. thanks**

Comment: Start from researching the Maps' API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/  and http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/  ...And look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First include the Google Maps API:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=YOUR_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

now

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var map = null;

function initialize() 
{
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
  {        
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("googleMap"));
    map.setUIToDefault();
  }
}

// your code:

function get_location()
{ 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(map);
}

function show_map(position)
{
    var latitude=position.coords.latitude; 
    var longitude=position.coords.longitude; 

    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(latitude, longitude), 13);
}

</script>
```

Comment: be sure to call the method "show_map" with the parameter position... maybe you should do something like:

function get_location()
{ 
    this.show_map(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(map));
}

Comment: By the way, I found this: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Comment: that's similar to what I did except that it uses the API in version 3 while mine is still in v2

Comment: I don't know why, but it didn't work for me for some reason. But I've got it anyway!